# Make the comeback

Tags: definite-article, colloquial-language

I was talking about the time I hurt myself and had to stop going to the gym and how I recovered and started lifting again. I said:
"The only thing that helped me to **make the comeback** was his words."

1. I know we usually say 'make a comeback' but since I was talking about a specific incident is it possible to say 'make **the** comeback' here?
2. Someone told me that only athletes, actors, politicians and the like make comebacks. Can I as a guy who's not a professional lifter use the word comeback in this context?

Answer (score 2):

Anyone can make a comeback, from any setback, it does not have to be a certain type of athlete.

But, it is "a" comeback, not "the" comeback, when referring to yourself.  Or you can say "my comeback."

When referring to others, it is "his" or "her" or "their" comeback.

Rarely one might hear the phrase "the comeback," in abstract terms, but I've only ever encountered it in song lyrics.

Answer (score 2):

1. It is "a comeback" or "my comeback" when you are talking about yourself.
2. Of course you can, anyone can, but you normally hear it used by those examples that you listed. Also, lifters are athletes just you're not a professional one.